# How do I remove whole sub-list from list, if i have only few element of the sub-list? python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to remove sub-list from list and gets this error:
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

I wish to remove the sub-list despite the fact that x have only few elemnt from sub-string

something like that:

```
list_a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

list_a.remove([1,3])

list_a

[4,5,6]
```

---

From comments below:

i got list of products:

```
products=[['0001', 'Hummus', 'Food', 'ISR', '10-04-2015'], ['0002', 'Guinness', 'Food', 'IRL', '11-04-2015']]
```

`lst[0]`, `lst[2]` and `lst[3]` are unique for each product. i wish to remove the whole sub list, by having this three elemnts like:

```
>>> products.remove(['0001', 'Food', 'ISR'])
>>> products
['0002', 'Guinness', 'Food', 'IRL', '11-04-2015']
```

.

```
def del_product(depot, product_data):
'''
    del_product
    delets a validated product data from the depot
    if such a product does not exist in the depot
    then no action is taken

    arguments:
    depot - list of lists
    product_data - list

    return value: boolean
'''

# Your code goes her

if validate_product_data(product_data)==True:
    for product in depot:
        if equal_products(product, product_data)==True:
            rem = set(product_data)
            for x in reversed(depot):
                if rem.issubset(x):
                    depot.remove(x)

            return True
        else:
            continue
    return False
```

Comment: What happened to the two?

Comment: Are you trying to get this result: `[[1], [4, 5, 6]]`?

Comment: What will be the output for `list_a=[[1,2,3],[1,4,3]]; list_a.remove([1,3])`?

Comment: I don't want the two. want to remove the whole sub-string by having the other elements in the sub-list.

Comment: probably the example with the numbers is not clear enough. i'll try to explain my problem.

Comment: @SharonTarrab: Next time, edit the question, rather than dumping code in the comments

Comment: sorry about that. thank you Eric

Comment: Better yet, read up on the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s and make sure that your code sample is still complete enough to represent problem X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if `[1,3]`  is a subset with [set.issubset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
list_a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

rem = set([1,3])

list_a[:] = [ x for x in list_a if not rem.issubset(x)]
print(list_a)
```

> s.issubset(t)  s <= t  test whether every element in s is in t

Using `list_a[:]` changes the original list.

With your products list  it is exactly the same:

```
products=[['0001', 'Hummus', 'Food', 'ISR', '10-04-2015'], ['0002', 'Guinness', 'Food', 'IRL', '11-04-2015']]

rem = set(['0001', 'Food', 'ISR'])

products[:] = [ x for x in products if not rem.issubset(x)]
print(products)
[['0002', 'Guinness', 'Food', 'IRL', '11-04-2015']]
```

Using a loop if it makes it easier to follow, you can combine reversed and issubset:

```
products=[['0001', 'Hummus', 'Food', 'ISR', '10-04-2015'], ['0002', 'Guinness', 'Food', 'IRL', '11-04-2015']]

rem = set(['0001', 'Food', 'ISR'])   

for x in reversed(products):
    if rem.issubset(x):
        products.remove(x)
print(products)
```

Comment: tiny question, what is the reason for using "reversed"?

Comment: If you don't use `reversed`, you end up messing up your `list` while trying to iterate through it.

Comment: You don't actually need to use `reversed`, you just want a copy of the list. You can use `for x in products[:]`.

Comment: @SharonTarrab, python has pointers to each object in the list  when it starts the iteration, if you remove elements while iterating you can end up missing elements. You could copy the list but using reversed means we don't need to hold another full list in memory

Comment: @EllaShar, reversed is a much more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It works great inside the function. but the changes in the list does not save outside the function as I need. how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: @SharonTarrab, how are you using it? The list should change if you pass the original list to the function

Comment: can you add the functions to pastebin, it is too hard to decipher in the comment. One definite problem is you are not using `[:]` or reversed

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah sorry, I edited my question. still trying to undersatnd how to work right in this website :)

Comment: are you passing depot into the function?

Comment: You also seem to be looping over depot twice in the loop?

Comment: i am. the function gets the list depot, that holds all the products, and product_data, list that hold three unique elements of the product.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i have to loop over it for the first time to find if the list depot at all contains the product i wish to remove.

Comment: I understood what is the problem. Thank you Padraic for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list_a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> bad = [1,3]
>>> list_a = [l for l in list_a if all(e not in l for e in bad)]
>>> list_a
[[4, 5, 6]]
```

Now that the actual question has been revealed:

```
>>> products=[['0001', 'Hummus', 'Food', 'ISR', '10-04-2015'], ['0002', 'Guinness', 'Food', 'IRL', '11-04-2015']]
>>> to_remove=['0001', 'Food', 'ISR']
>>> products = [l for l in products if [l[0], l[2], l[3]] != to_remove]
>>> products
[['0002', 'Guinness', 'Food', 'IRL', '11-04-2015']]
```

It might be good to move to an OO approach, with a `Product` or `Food` object containing `code`, `name`, `category`, `label`, and `date` attributes.

Comment: for `list_a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]; bad = [1,4]` this will return `[]`. Is this what the OP wanted?

Comment: From what I gathered, yes.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_a = [sub for sub in list_a if not all(i in [1, 3] for i in sub)]
```

Comment: @sshashank124: `not any(cond for ...)` short circuits just as well as `all(not cond for ...)` (ie, TigerhawkT3's answer). IMO though, this one reads better

Comment: Change `not any` to `not all` here, and you meet the OP's updated requirements

Comment: @Eric Thank you. Didn't realize such a requirement.

Comment: Don't fret - in the context of the question as it originally appeared, this answer fit the requirements.